# Windows presentation foundation tool or sdk to load pdf and dwg files

Tags: wpf

I have a request from the customer to make a tool that loads png, jpg, tiff, pdf, dwg file formats. Buying a tool or sdk or something to help me build this is an option, as long as it is not a per unit price. Does anybody know a good tool (apart from Atalasoft DotImage, they don't want that.. not sure why..).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try bravaviewer, it supports load many formats,like pdf, dwg and so on, more formats see http://www.bravaviewer.com/formats